# Is $\widehat{K}L$ complete?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $\widehat{K}$ be a completion with respect to some valuation on $K$. Let $L$ be a finite separable extension of $K$.

When regarded as a subfield of $\widehat{L}$, is $\widehat{K}L$ complete? For example, I can't see why $\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{2})$ is complete.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, it follows that $\widehat KL$ is a finite extension of $\widehat K$.

In general, if $(K, \|\cdot\|)$ is a complete normed space, and $V$ is a finite dimensional $K$-vector space, then any two norms on $V$ are equivalent, and moreover, $V$ is complete with respect to any of these norms. To see the fact that $V$ is complete, observe that $V$ is complete with respect to the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathrm{sup}}$, and hence is complete with respect to any norm.

The following theorem follows easily as a corollary of this:

> Let $(\widehat K, |\cdot|)$ be a complete field and $[M:\widehat K]<\infty$. If $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ are absolute values on $M$ extending $|\cdot|$ on $\widehat K$, then
>
> 1. $|\cdot|_1=|\cdot|_2$
> 2. $M$ is complete with respect to $|\cdot|_1$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer!
The point that I am confused is exactly the part 2 of the statement you gave. Could you give more explanation?

Comment: @user109870 I've added a bit more detail to show where point 2 is coming from. The result is really just a rehashing of the result on fd complete normed (Banach) spaces, the proof of which is a technical induction proof.

Comment: Ok, I have looked up the proof for 1 in the case of Banach spaces. However, they seem to use the property of $\mathbb{R}$ in an essential way, and I am not sure how it generalizes to arbitrary complete fields.

Comment: Ah I see. The more general proof is similar, and uses the sup-norm in place of the Euclidean norm. See Thm 4.2 here http://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/iii/Local_Fields_2011.pdf