# Is $ \widehat L(α)$ is $ \widehat {L(α)}$ ? (^ means completion)

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, formal-completions

Let $L$ be algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $α∈\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}$.
Let $ \widehat L$ be completion of $L$.
Is  $ \widehat L(α)$ is  $ \widehat {L(α)}$ ?

It plausibly true, but I cannot prove this. Perhaps there maybe counterexamples.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you already know that any *finite* extension of a complete non-archimedean valued fields has a unique extension of the valuation, and is complete with respect to that extended valuation? If so, this result easily extends to any algebraic extension, and then both inclusion you want to proof should be straightforward to show.

Comment: Compare also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1541766/96384.